# How to count duplicate words in array and add a count number to EACH word?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, count

My goal is to turn

```
['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon']
```

into

```
'sara', 'mike', 'sara(1)','sara(2)' 'Jon'
```

Ive seen some solutions when counting the total number of duplicates, however, couldnt find anything for what I am trying to do..

ps. I cannot use sort() as the names should stay where they were in the original array..

I tried using a regular for loop but nothing really worked, I also think a map approach would probably be good, but cant figure out how to do that.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I actually came up with this here:

```
function words(arr){
  var result=[];
  var count=0;
 for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (result.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
    result.push(arr[i]);    
    }
    else {
        count++;
        result.push(arr[i]+"("+count+")");
    }

 }
 return result.join(',');
}

words(['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon'] );
```

and it works except it returns 'sara,mike,sara(1),sara(2),Jon' instead of 'sara','mike,'sara(1)','sara(2)','Jon'

Anyone knows how to change that? I tried join, split etc already..

Comment: If you found solutions for counting duplicates, then can't you just modify the string whenever the count is greater than 1?

Comment: no,it doesn't work or I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Then show what you've tried so that we can help you understand where you made a mistake.

Comment: @javascripting Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/934/

Comment: Note that your solution works only if just one name is repeating, but if more than one name is repeating your solution will fail (i.e. `['sara','mike', 'sara', 'mike']`)

Answer (score 1):

```
var nameArr = ['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon'];
var nameTrack = {};
var resultArr = nameArr.map(function(name) {
  if(typeof nameTrack[name] === 'undefined') {
    nameTrack[name] = 0;
    return name;
  }
  return name + '(' + ++nameTrack[name] + ')';
});
```

Some points of explanation:

You can't just use `nameTrack[name]` cast to a boolean on the 4th line because 0 is non-truthy.

The `++` preceeds `nameTrack[name]` so that the incrementation happens first.  If you put it afterwards, the number would only increment after the string was formed.

Map is an array function that takes each value of the array, modifies it, and returns it to the array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: You forgot to assign the new array returned by the `map` function to some variable (i.e. `var result = nameArr.map(...);`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function countWords (words) {
    var wordsCounter = {}, results = [];
    words.forEach(function (word) {
        if (!wordsCounter.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
            results.push(word);
            wordsCounter[word] = 1;
        }
        else {
            results.push(word + '(' + (wordsCounter[word]++) + ')');
        }
    });
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a regular loop solution.  tested and got your expected results

```
var myArray = ['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon'] 

                var arrayResult = [];

                for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
                {
                    arrayResult.push(countPlease(i));

                }
                console.dir(arrayResult);
                //'sara', 'mike', 'sara(1)','sara(2)' 'Jon'

            function countPlease(index)//index of where you're current at
            {
                //loop backword
                var txt = myArray[index]; // don't count
                var c = 0;
                for (var i=index-1;i>-1;i--) //don't count itself
                {
                    if(myArray[i]==txt)
                    {
                        c++
                    }
                }
                if(c>0)
                {
                    return txt+ ' (' + c+')'
                }
                else
                return txt;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c1smp3zj/) is a JSFiddle and here is a solution:

```
var a = ['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon'];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var repeated = 1;
    for(var j=i; j<a.length; j++){
        if(i == j){
        continue;
    }
    if(a[i].toLowerCase() == a[j].toLowerCase()){
        a[j] = a[i]+repeated;
        repeated++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the 2 loops-and i=0 and j=i ? As I understand, the first word (f.e. sara is being compared to every other word in the array because of the second loop, then the second word is being compared to every other word etc-: i starts with 'sara' and j starts with wherever i starts?

Comment: Why not just `for (var j = i+1;..` instead of `if (i == j) continue;` ? .. Also, this solution is O(n^2) complexity, means if `a = ['mike', 'sara'... <repeat  sara millions of times>...];`, you'll compare `mike` with each of these `sara`'s unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of an **object**, which counts the words:

```
if(key in obj) { // Found the same word
    ...
    obj[key] += 1; 
} else { // Only one time found
    ...
    obj[key] = 0;
}
```

In total:

```
var names = ['sara', 'mike', 'sara', 'sara', 'Jon'];

function countWords(arr) {
    var res = [];
    var obj = {};

    names.forEach(function(name) {
        if(name in obj) {
            obj[name] += 1;
            res.push(name + "(" + obj[name] + ")");
        } else {
            obj[name] = 0;
            res.push(name);
        }
    });

    return res.join(",");
}

var res = countWords(names);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You should iterate over `arr` rather than `names`

Answer (score -2):

```js
var arr = ['sara', 'mike', 'sara','sara','Jon'];
var number_detail = {};
$.each(arr, function(key, val){
  if (typeof number_detail[val] != 'undefined'){
    var cur_count = number_detail[val];
    number_detail[val] = cur_count+1;
    arr[key] = val+'('+number_detail[val]+')';
  }
  else {
    number_detail[val] = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't really need any external libraries

Comment: @Russbear, Yeah, the original for loop in js can be applied here. But just more prefer jQuery